# How To Stop Overwriting Directories When Pushing to Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku, directory

This seems simple enough but I can't find a fix. I have a django app on heroku. I'm using heroku as a staging environment. My app uses a directory `media` for images and files uploaded from the admin pages.

When I `git push heroku master` it destroys this directory even though it's not added in the repo.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't provide persistent storage.

On `git push` your code is transformed into a *slug* and then it is distributed to a dyno that your application runs in. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler for details.

If you want persistent storage you should integrate your application with AWS S3 (Simple Storage Service) or some other service.

Comment: How to upload to S3 from Django: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319923/how-to-upload-a-file-with-django-python-and-s3 How to serve static files from S3 using Django: http://wavesandmaps.com/utilizing-s3-for-a-heroku-django-app/